# Does movement whilst hidden provoke opportunity attacks?

Tags: dnd-4e, stealth, opportunity-attack

Playing a rogue in my first two D&D Sessions ever thanks to online tabletop (a god send, really!)

However, I've come to learn that it's not an easy task (however, my healer has kept me from death not once, not twice, but three times!) and I have successfully made it to level 2.

Though I have this question:

In the PHB Book (page 183 under 'Gain Combat Advantage') the rogue can take a standard action to make a feint or create a diversion to hide (next listing under).

If the diversion is successful and my character enters stealth, while he was within threaten range of an enemy, and uses a move action does he provoke an Opportunity attack to move away from the enemy?

On the other hand, it seems that if I were to start an encounter in stealth and move past an enemy, so long as I passed my stealth check, he could not gain an Opportunity attack...

Are these scenarios related? What's your take?

Thanks! PHB Citations are very welcome as I learn about this.

Comment: It should probably be noted that the Bluff skill "feint/create a diversion to hide" simply causes the monster to grant combat advantage, and does not explicitly grant superior cover or total concealment so you can't use it to make a stealth check to hide.

Answer (score 15):

Hidden creatures never provoke opportunity attacks. If they enter Hidden from *Create a diversion to hide*, they'll be fine. From the DDI Compendium:

> ### Hidden
>
> When a creature is hidden from an enemy, the creature is silent and invisible to that enemy. A creature normally uses the Stealth skill to become hidden. See also invisible.
>
> ### Invisible
>
> If a creature is invisible, it has several advantages against creatures that can’t see it: It has total concealment against them, **it doesn’t provoke opportunity attacks** from them, and they grant combat advantage to it.

(Emphasis added.)

Since you're using the PHB1 Stealth rules, you should be aware they were revised significantly as of PHB2. The most recent stealth rules are available on page 20 of the [Player's Handbook errata](http://www.wizards.com/dnd/files/UpdatePH.pdf), which you can read for free online. [The Rules of Hidden Club](http://www.giantitp.com/forums/showthread.php?455236-The-Rules-Of-Hidden-Club-%28saved-from-Wizards-community-forums%29) comes with a complete and thorough explanation of how being Hidden works, which is surprisingly not explained in such a straightforward manner in the Handbooks.

Bear in mind, though, the Rules of Hidden Club for the most part don't apply to *Create a diversion to hide*, as it bypasses those rules and [allows you to hide in plain sight](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/31126/1204) unlike a regular stealth check.

Answer (score 0):

> On the other hand, it seems that if I were to start an encounter in stealth and move past an enemy, so long as I passed my stealth check, he could not gain an Opportunity attack...

In a combat scenario, you cannot simply walk past an enemy and maintain the Hidden condition - as soon as you attack, or break from cover, you are seen. However, you *do* keep the benefits of being hidden for the duration of the *single action* that reveals your location - this is how attacks hidden from cover, or the use of Deft Strike (a single action move+attack) can gain you Combat Advantage and thus Sneak Attack bonus damage.

That rule would equally apply to a single Move action taken to get past someone, meaning you could indeed run past someone and not trigger AoO if you started your turn hidden from them - however, you would not still be Hidden from that enemy at the end of that Move action.

It is also possible to be Hidden, take a Move action to move past someone and end up in another position where it is possible to use Stealth skill to hide from them - and roll Stealth to hide again.

If you can, find a way to maintain stealth whilst moving close to the enemy. At low levels, that might be cover or concealment very close to the enemy (imagine a room full of furniture with the rogue hiding behind it, or a half-closed door, dark shadows etc - but the important thing is that the DM rules the items give cover or concealment affecting the enemy). If you can find these, you can move around a foe without risking attacks of opportunity, and without losing your Hidden condition (well, provided you don't attack anyone)

Bear in mind though that many enemies are not stupid - once you are revealed after the first time, the enemy will have a good idea of where you are even when Hidden and can use their action to e.g. walk around the cover, find you automatically and attack you, or use an area-based attack where they don't even have to see you. The Hidden rules in 4E can get quite complicated in this regard and take a few times read through, ideally with DM and stealthy player discussing them. On the plus side, if you follow them carefully they do work nicely in 4E's tactical system, and can be a lot of fun.